# sed find and replace string surrounded by [] output to file

Tags: sed

Have a file with the following

```
"SCAN_IN[0]" : input;
```

Want to use sed to find and replace with scan_0

I am using the following command

```
sed  's/SCAN_IN[]0[]/scan_0/' fileA > fileB
```

This is what i am getting

```
"scan_00]" : input;
```

I want

```
"scan_0" : input;
```

Comment: Use `sed 's/SCAN_IN\[0]/scan_0/'  fileA > fileB`. Why did you use `[]`?

Comment: or `tr -d '[]' < fileA`

Comment: Do you only want to do this for index 0, or for any number that may happen to appear in the square brackets? Also, should SCAN_IN be a full word (array name, perhaps), or is it OK if the change will also be made from `RESCAN_IN[0]` to `RESCAN_0`?  The "correct solution" will make that change too - it does not check to see if `SCAN_IN` is a complete word.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I am pretty sure the OP wanted to capture all opening and closing brackets and the digit 0 - but he didn't use a quantifier after the character class. See my comment above too, regarding your solution (and, rather, the missing "request for clarification from the OP" before you posted your answer).

Comment: @Cyrus - the OP also needs to remove the word `IN` from the array name. You won't be able to do that with `tr`, without disturbing other things. (And, in fact, if there are also other brackets in the string, the solution would give the wrong answer for that reason too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SCAN_IN[]0[]` pattern matches `SCAN_IN` first and then `[]0[]` matches one char: either `]`, or `0`, or `[` (due to "smart placement" when the unescaped `]` located right after the opening bracket expression `[` (or `[^` is it is a negated bracket expression) is treated as a literal `]`  and not the closing bracket expression char).

In your string, `SCAN_IN[]0[]` matches `SCAN_IN[` and thus the result of the replacement is **scan_0**`0]" : input;`.

You may use

```
sed 's/SCAN_IN\[0]/scan_0/' fileA > fileB
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/jH845Q):

```
s='"SCAN_IN[0]" : input;'
sed 's/SCAN_IN\[0]/scan_0/'  <<< "$s"
# => "scan_0" : input;
```

Answer (score 0):

I will make a few assumptions:

You want `"SCAN_IN[?]"` to be replaced with `"scan_?"` where **`?`** may be any string of (zero or more) consecutive non-closing-bracket characters. This means three things (at least): that you must convert from upper-case in the input to lower-case in the output (which is pretty odd); that the double-quotes are part of the matching pattern - so that only SCAN_IN is matched, but not for example **RE**SCAN_IN; and that you want this done for anything within brackets, not just for the single character `0`.

Also, you don't care where the pattern appears (whether it's before additional text like `: input` or anywhere else), and you must make the same change even if the pattern appears more than once on the same line. (So we need the `g` flag.)

The `sed` command that can do all that is:

```
sed -E 's/"SCAN_IN\[([^]]+)]"/"scan_\1"/g'
```

Here are a few examples:

```
$ echo '"SCAN_IN[0]" : input' | sed -E 's/"SCAN_IN\[([^]]*)]"/"scan_\1"/g'

"scan_0" : input


$ echo '"TO_SCAN_IN[0]" : input' | sed -E 's/"SCAN_IN\[([^]]*)]"/"scan_\1"/g'

"TO_SCAN_IN[0]" : input



$ echo '"SCAN_IN[0]" : input "RESCAN_IN[1]" "SCAN_IN[37]" "SCAN[0]"' | 
                                 sed -E 's/"SCAN_IN\[([^]]+)]"/"scan_\1"/g'

"scan_0" : input "RESCAN_IN[1]" "scan_37" "SCAN[0]"
```